# Jest coverage doesn't pick up on vue functional component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a Vue functional component, with some tests using Jest, but the coverage say 0 for this file. Is this the right way to test functional components in Vue?

this is an example of my component

```
<template functional>
      <div :class="['name', ...props.extraClasses]">
          {{ props.itemName }}
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        itemName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        extraClasses: {
            type: Array,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

This is what 1 of my tests look like

```
test('it works correctly with all props', () => {

    const wrapper = shallow(cmp, {
        context: {
          props: {
            itemName: 'item name',
            extraClasses: ['extra1', 'extra2'],
          }
        },
      })
    const name = wrapper.find('.name');
    expect(name.classes()).toEqual(['name', 'extra1', 'extra2']);
    expect(name.text()).toBe('item name');
});
```

After I run jest, I'm seeing the coverage is 0, and the uncovered lines are the props.
Is there any other way to test the functional component?

And how do I get the jest coverage to work correctly for this test file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is reported to be fixed in version 4
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/88
I tried upgrading to vue-jest@4.0.0-beta.2 and confirmed this issue was fixed